# How many fmaps to lift four layers?

Tags: haskell

You use fmap to lift a function over some context:

```
fmap succ [1] = [2]
```

You can use function composition to lift over two layers of context:

```
(fmap . fmap) succ [[1]] = [[2]]
```

And because fmap for functions is equal to (.), this can also be written as:

```
fmap fmap fmap succ [[1]] = [[2]]
```

What about three layers of context?

```
fmap . fmap . fmap = 
(fmap . fmap) . fmap = 
fmap (fmap . fmap) fmap = 
fmap (fmap fmap fmap) fmap = 
(fmap . fmap fmap) fmap fmap = 
fmap fmap (fmap fmap) fmap fmap = 
(fmap fmap . fmap) fmap fmap fmap = 
(fmap . fmap) fmap fmap fmap fmap fmap = 
fmap fmap fmap fmap fmap fmap fmap fmap
```

Eight! We just went from 5 (2 of which where infix) to 8.

How many fmaps in a row do I need to lift over four layers of context? A lot apparently, so many that I can't figure it out trough bruteforce. Is it even possible, does the pattern stop at 3?

Comment: Just to be clear, you know that you can write `(fmap . fmap . fmap . fmap) succ [[[[1]]]]`, and you're looking for a way to rewrite it as a curiosity?

Comment: @ChrisMartin Correct.